# How to find the area of $D = \{(x, y, z) \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1~\text{and}~z = 0\}$ under a linear transformation

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, analytic-geometry

Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the set $D = \{(x, y, z) \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1~\text{and}~z = 0\}$. Let $T :  \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(x, y, z) = (2x − y + z, x − y + 10z, 3x − 7y + 2z)$. Find the area of $T(D)$.

understanding the body to calculate the area :
$$z = 0 \implies T(D) = T(x,y,0) = (2x-y,x-y,3x-7y)$$

Now let's name:
\begin{align*}
x' & = 2x-y\\
y' & = x-y\\
z' & = 3x-7y
\end{align*}

Solving the equations we get $(x'-y')^2 + (x'-2y')^2 = 1$.  This is the body of several parabolas (I think).  How can I calculate the area?

Comment: You're more likely to get a response if you show that you have attempted the problem yourself.

Comment: i did i wasted 2 papers for nothing the equation :

Comment: (x'-y')^2 + (x-2y')^2 = 1

Comment: Try to edit your question to show your workings out and thoughts

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Sorry but the set you defined consists of a circle $S^1$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, what do you mean for area? The area of the disk enclosed by this circle?

Answer (score 1):

This is an easier question than you are making it.

What does the transformation do the area square that encloses the circle?

Does it transform the area of all shapes in the plane equally?  (yes it does)

What does it to the area of the square with vertices $(0,0,0),(1,0,0), (0,1,0),(1,1,0)$?

This square is easy to work with.  And we know the area is 1.

$T(1,0,0) = (2,1,3)\\
T(0,1,0) = (-1,-1,-7)$

As for the other vertexes $T\mathbf 0 = \mathbf 0$

$T(1,1,0) = T(1,0,0)+T(0,1,0)$

But we don't really need to worry about the other vertices as

$\|(2,1,3)\times(-1,-1,-7)\|$

Tells us the area of the parallelogram.

This tells you how much areas in the plane will scale.

What was the area of D before the transformation?

Comment: i didn't understand could you explain deeply please

Comment: could you explain what did you do why did you picked two points like that and find the area of the parallelogram using cross product

Comment: I picked those vectors, because they will define a square of area 1.  They are also principal vectors, which makes them easy to work with.  As for the cross product, the magnitude of the cross product equals the area of the parallelogram defined by the vectors.